# How to make variables computed after its initializing

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I am trying to set a variable that will depend on two others, but I don't want that computed 
variable reacts on the initializing of one of these vars.

```
var viewModel = function() {
    var self = this;
    self.first = ko.observable("");
    self.second = ko.observable();

    self.doSmth = function() {
        self.second(self.second() + 1);
    };

    self.init = function(o){
        self.second(o);
    };

    self.comp = ko.computed(function(){
        self.first();
        self.second();
        alert(self.second());
    });
};
var vm = new viewModel();
ko.applyBindings(vm);
vm.init(111);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/TCAHS/1/

Alert message should appear only when I click on the button and dependent variable value was changed. And no messages with 'undefined' and init value '111'. Is there any built-in solution? Thanks.

Comment: You can use the `{deferEvaluation : true}` option on your computed and explicitly call in the `doSmth`http://jsfiddle.net/bWLXh/. But your design is very strange: you don't use the computed itself anywhere it seems you only want to take advantages of the automatic reavaluation... can you please elaborate on your use case and write a little bit more what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Nice solution, but it needs to call computed method explicit it each place. I want to avoid it. And you are right, I don't need computed value itself. I just want one place in code, where I can handle changes of some variable (more than two, of course).

Comment: If you don't need a computed, then don't use a computed :) just manually `subscribe` on your dependent properties and you can do this in the init: http://jsfiddle.net/v2j2k/

Answer (score 0):

I'll go with the easy solution... what about setting a flag to check whether the observable has been initialized, something like:

```
var viewModel = function() {
    var self = this;
    self.first = ko.observable("");
    self.second = ko.observable();

    self.doSmth = function() {
        self.second(self.second() + 1);
    };

    self.init = function(o){
        self.second(o);
    };

    var initialized = false;

    self.comp = ko.computed(function(){
        self.first();
        self.second();

        if (initialized) {
            alert(self.second());
        }
        initialized = true;
    });
};
var vm = new viewModel();
ko.applyBindings(vm);
vm.init(111);
```

And here's the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arielsvn/QPr9f/).